# "Disconnected by Server: BadPaddingException"

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, networking

I have not opened up my Minecraft launcher for nearly a year. However, when I updated to Minecraft 1.6.2 and the new launcher recently, every server I attempt to connect to seems to have some kind of problem, leaving me with this every time I try to connect to any server:

[image: Screenshot of the disconnection screen. It reads "Disconnected by Server: BadPaddingException : Blocktype mismatch: 0 @ sun.security.rsa.RSAPadding:328".]

I have checked and double checked every server and they are definitely up to date and my internet connection is working. I also guarantee you that my launcher is the official Minecraft launcher and I am playing online with a premium account.

**Why is this issue cropping up? What does the text mean and how can I fix this?**

Comment: That exception has to do with a failed exchange of encryption keys. Are these "offline" servers, or are you maybe using an unofficial launcher?

Comment: I am using the official Minecraft launcher from mojang. As for if these servers are offline, I suspected this too  but I tried about 10 large servers I do not think that they would all be offline at the same time

Comment: "Offline" servers are also called cracked servers in Minecraft. They allow people to join without signing into Mojang's central servers with an authorized and paid-for account.

Comment: By "the official Minecraft launcher from mojang", do you mean the same one from pre-1.6 versions? Because the old launcher was replaced by a new one within the last six months or so.

Comment: @BillyMailman This is the new launcher; you can't play 1.6.2 in the old launcher.

Comment: @Unionhawk between the way he worded it, and the fact that the error relates to security, which is partly handled by the launcher, I was kinda checking to make sure he hadn't tried to make it work.

Comment: I updated to Minecraft 1.6.2 meaning that I reinstalled the new launcher

Comment: Maybe delete you .minecraft folder and get a fresh install, You might have old stuff in there

Comment: Searches indicate that this is an error that sometimes comes up with badly-written Bukkit plugins that do their own networking (there is a top-list voting confirmation plugin in particular that seems to suffer from it). It seems unlikely that every single server you've tried has the same bad plugin installed though, so there must be something else going on. Could you maybe provide a list of the servers that cause this, at least the publicly-accessible ones?

Comment: Firstly, are you using 'vanilla' Minecraft or do you have mods? And secondly is your version of Java up to date? The fact it's coming from the standard rsa encryption methods could mean that it was a bug in Java that got patched. Alternatively do you have a log file with more details of the exception? It could be a bug in Minecraft or any installed mods, in which case knowing which class and method are calling the RSA encryption function would be quite useful.

Answer (score 1):

I've googled `BadPaddingException` and this is what it means: the wrong key was used to decrypt the data. It is an error for Minecraft to fix, so what you should do is report a bug to Mojang and they should fix it in later updates.

Answer (score 0):

Try one of these things. if minecraft doesnt work after doing these things you might have a modded client or some kind of virus.

1. Check all minecraft files with anti-virus if anyone of them has a virus delete it then run minecraft
2. Delete all minecraft files than redownload it from the official website
3. If theres any type of internet proxy or restriction then remove it
4. Try playing it at home and not work / school / public library there might be a restriction at those places
5. Try it on another computer

Answer (score -6):

Delete the Minecraft files by going to the Start Menu then Run, and type `%appdata%` and then delete the **.minecraft** folder. Then start the launcher, log in, and it will update all your files.

**Be careful! This will delete your worlds, so back them up first!** Back them up by copying the `saves` folder inside `.minecraft` to your Desktop before deleting anything. After that, delete the `.minecraft` folder. Once the files are updated, go to AppData, double click `.minecraft`, delete the `saves` folder, then copy your backup of the `saves` folder from your Desktop to the `.minecraft` folder.

Comment: How does this resolve the issue?  It sounds more like it just forces a reinstall.  That might fix it, but there's no real explanation of what's going on.

Comment: There is no need to Capitalise Every Word or use ALL CAPS FOR EMPHASIS. I've done an edit to make this more readable.